# Native android app posting to a user's wall...it works for me, but no one else

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created an android app that will post information to a user's wall.  I went through the steps of creating the app in facebook, using the key to create the hash.  It has gone well, and on two of my devices, I can post the info to whatever facebook account I log into.  Once signed in, it doesn't ask me to again.

However, when I gave this to some other people to test, they are getting an authentication error.  It's along the lines of "android key mismatch, your key doesn't match your application settings."

I've tried to get into the facebook app page for my app, to check settings there...but whenever I try to get there through the Facebook developers app page, I get redirected to my regular facebook page with "Your pages", and it lists the apps I've created there.  But none of those pages lead back to the app setup/key page.

That's just kind of a side note...the real question is why does posting work fine for me, but not someone else who uses the same app?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had the wrong key value stored in facebook.  For some reason it was letting me post, but no one else could.  I got the new key value from the same keystore I sign my apps with, and now it works for everyone else.